# Unable to add a link using <a> to a <li> tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have created a partial view which will show the menu with unordered list. I want to add links to each li element. I have done my research and tried different ways like giving relative path, absolute path etc. but it does not open the view page. It shows 404 error in browser.
Am I missing to add something in partial view which can then open the view page on clicking the li tag item.

```
<li><a href="~/Views/Powershell/PwrCmts.cshtml">Powershell Comments</a></li>
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In MVC you never link to cshtml files, the urls are always `controller/action`, optionally followed by parameters, separated by `/` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should change link like "/Controller/Action".

Code at the below will work fine if the names of action and controller are correct.

```
<li><a href="/Powershell/PwrCmts">Powershell Comments</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use @url.action() method.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).